# Making current_user available in ActionCable channels using bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt, actioncable

I'm trying to make `current_user` available in my channel actions.. This is the first time I'm diving into `ActionCable` and the tutorial I'm following is using `Devise` and I am not..

In `channels/application_cable/connection.rb`. They have

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble with the protected method. I'm not sure how to verify the user from this file using `bcrypt`.. Also the directory this file is under seems to be likened to helpers for ActionCable, am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like you are asking how to build an entire authentication system. bcrypt is just a library for encrypting passwords. You actually have to write all the logic of authenticating users, serializing/unserializing the user from the session etc. If you don't want Devise than use just Warden and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "Also the directory this file is under seems to be likened to helpers for ActionCable, am I correct in thinking this?" - no. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: I already have authentication in place using bcrypt. I guess my question would be "what can I access from here?". I see from the Rails Guides I can access the cookies but I can't seem to get ahold of my `session[:user_id]`

Comment: "The WebSocket server doesn't have access to the session, but it has access to the cookies. This can be used when you need to handle authentication."